# How to add and run a javascript for only on firefox not on others?

Tags: javascript

How to add and run a javascript for only on firefox not on others?

I've to add a javascript on a page and it should only work on firefox. not on IE

Comment: What an odd thing to be asked to do - why would someone want you to break the experience for half of the browsers in the world?

Comment: why is this being voted down?

Comment: I can't find anything odd about this requirement?

Comment: +1 for teaching others a lesson (don't use browser detection)

Answer (score 2):

Never use browser detection, use [**object detection**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) (if your intent was using some objects/methods available only on some browsers.)

Answer (score 1):

use **[navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.navigator)** object

**[navigator.appName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Navigator.appName)**

> Returns the official name of the
>   browser.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `navigator.appName`, you could use the [browser detection script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) from Quirksmode, then use an if statement to check if it's Firefox.  This will nicely prepare browser information in an object for you, so you can pick out individual information such as version number, etc.